# Windows Explorer Hangs on Right-Click

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I am not sure if this is the right site to post this one as I typically post coding questions on stackoverflow. But I'll ask anyways and hopefully someone can move it if it's incorrect.

Currently I have a customer built PC, utilizing an Intel i7 chip, 1300WATT PSU, 8Gigs of RAM, and two video cards.

Originally I had the one video card (NVIDIA) that used the PSU and had two DVI output. After purchasing a third monitor I installed another ATI) graphics card not needed any PSU connectors.

After installing and restarting, I noticed that when I right-click on my desktop, or through Windows Explorer it will hang, freeze then restarted. Sometimes after Windows Explorer restarts the problem dissipates.

I checked to make sure everything was connected properly and it was. I repaired the ATI Catalyst Control Center to see if that had an issue, and I checked to see if either video card required updated drivers. Nothing worked.

I tried restarting my PC and that didn't work. I tried using ShellXView (I forgot what it's actually called) and tried closed processes but that didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea what could have caused this orpossible solutions I should try?<

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install (even if it was uninstalled) any software that modifies the context menu (the "right-click menu")? Things like Archiver software commonly do this, but I've seen many other apps that do as well.

Answer (score 13):

Download [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html), disable all ATI-related shell extensions, one by one if you can. ATI installs a context menu handler that displays the "Catalyst Control Center" menu item, and I've found it unstable, besides being completely unnecessary.

Comment: +1: Context Menu hangs are almost exclusively the domain of buggy shell extensions.  ShellExView is the best tool for disabling them until you find the offender.

Answer (score 2):

If you know when this behavior started to occur, organize the ShellExView list by install date to quickly determine the cause to the behaviour