# Right click on mouse crashes Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, crash, right-click

Whenever I click the right button on my USB mouse or trackpad of my laptop, Windows Explorer will crash and restart. All windows opened will close.

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise. Has anyone else faced such a situation before?

This happened just after I plugged in a USB 3.0 hard drive to my laptop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Explorer Hangs on Right-Click](http://superuser.com/questions/248631/windows-explorer-hangs-on-right-click)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a buggy context menu hook. If it started right after a USB drive was inserted then it's likely that either the drive came preloaded with "value add" crapware (I'm looking at you, SanDisk) or that the USB drive was infected with a piece of autorun malware that hooks the context menu in Explorer.

Look through the registered shell extensions with [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and look through the shell menu handlers with [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) for suspicious entries. Don't go disabling things willy-nilly, but going through the (admittedly long) list of items may yield some answers. Anything from Microsoft is safe and may be very important, you're looking for entries which don't name a Publisher or that was modified near the time the problem started is immediately suspect.

If it is malware then you can run some diagnostics and post the logs at various analysis and removal forums like [Bleeping Computer](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/), [Malwarebytes](http://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php) or [247fixes](http://www.247fixes.com/forums/) for a volunteer to look at and advise removal steps.

Answer (score 0):

In my machine, the culprit found by use of ShellExView was (strangely enough) from McAfee:

```
==================================================
Extension Name    : McCtxFrmWrk Class
Disabled          : Yes
Type              : Context Menu
Description       : McAfee ContextMenu Framework
Version           : 15,0,179,0
Product Name      : McAfee SecurityCenter
Company           : McAfee, Inc.
My Computer       : No
Desktop           : No
Control Panel     : No
My Network Places : No
Entire Network    : No
Remote Computer   : No
Filename          : c:\PROGRA~1\mcafee\msc\MCCTXM~1.DLL
CLSID             : {CCA9EFD3-29ED-430A-BA6D-E6BBFF0A60C2}
File Created Time : 2012-11-30 12:43:20
CLSID Modified Time: 2016-12-15 11:12:15
Microsoft         : No
File Extensions   : *, .lnk, Folder, lnkfile, opensearchfilefolderresult
File Attributes   : A
File Size         : 374,800
.NET Extension    : No
Digital Signature : 
Missing File      : No
==================================================
```