# Explorer.exe Shutdown when copy or cut files and folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'v a problem with my Windows 7 Pro
that is when i copy or cut any file from any folder to another it crashes and close then relaunch explorer.exe
how could i solve this problem ?
any help?
Thanks

Comment: please download this reg file from my SkyDrive:

http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full.reg

and make a double click on the file to import it.
When the Windows Explorer crashes, Windows Error Reporting Service creates a dmp file under C:\Localdumps. Please upload the dump file (compressed 7z or RAR to reduce the size).

After you generated the dumps, download and import this regfile:

http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full_uninstall.reg

to stop the dump creation.

Comment: it's about 80mb zipped i'm uploading right now , thanks for reply

Comment: ok, use skydrive dropbox or a fast 1 click hoster.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to cut or copy?  Does it behave the same way whether you right-click the file and pick Copy (or cut), or use keyboard shortcuts (ctrl-c)? Have you seen this question: [Right click on mouse crashes Windows Explorer](http://superuser.com/questions/271118/right-click-on-mouse-crashes-windows-explorer)

Comment: uploading at ex.ua , i'm using right-click the file or filder and copy or cut and using keyboard shortcuts even

Comment: yeah i see it , it talks about infected with virus and my computer does not

Comment: here is the dump file http://fs174.www.ex.ua/load/02894a99d00181d7a18be054da7b7570/46126806/explorer.exe.9368.rar

Comment: the link doesn't work for me.

Comment: ok i will upload it to dropbox

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35493158/explorer.exe.9368.rar

Comment: @magicandre1981 are you there?

Answer (score 2):

the dump is not useful. You get a "Stack overflow" exception. I see you use some 3rd party shellextensions. Use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable extensions like Nokia PC Suite 7, SkyDrive and *TeraCopy*.

Btw, you should also install the Windows 7 Sp1.