# Explorer.exe crashes and restarts, faulting module Comctl32.dll

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, crash

I've changed the mainboard, CPU and SSD. Reinstalled original Windows 8.1 from USB and DVD many times. I have external graphic card (Gigabyte GTX650 OC) which I tested on another system, also tested only on integrated graphic card and with other graphic card (MSI N210). Tested RAMs with memtest+ but I still got following error. What can cause this error? I have two USB 3.0 external drives connected and a USB WiFi. I also have Eset Nod32 antivirus, Cobian backup installed.

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54503a3a
Faulting module name: Comctl32.dll, version: 6.10.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x5450590a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000007956
Faulting process ID: 0xeb8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0b72e28643b26
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\
amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17415_none_6240486fecbd8abb
\Comctl32.dll
Report ID: 5311119e-2326-11e5-8258-bc3a290d6513
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Here is a dump file created after explorer.exe crash: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8549949/explorer.exe.3768.dmp.7z

Visual Studio provides the following dump summary:

```
Dump Summary
------------
Dump File:  explorer.exe.3768.dmp : C:\explorer.exe.3768.dmp
Last Write Time:    5.7.2015 17:58:52
Process Name:   explorer.exe : C:\Windows\explorer.exe
Process Architecture:   x64
Exception Code: 0xC0000005
Exception Information:  The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Heap Information:   Present

System Information
------------------
OS Version: 6.3.9600
CLR Version(s): 

Modules
-------
Module Name Module Path Module Version
----------- ----------- --------------
explorer.exe    C:\Windows\explorer.exe 6.3.9600.17415
ntdll.dll   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll   6.3.9600.17415
kernel32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
KERNELBASE.dll  C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll  6.3.9600.17415
apphelp.dll C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll 6.3.9600.17415
msvcrt.dll  C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll  7.0.9600.17415
oleaut32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
combase.dll C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll 6.3.9600.17415
powrprof.dll    C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll    6.3.9600.17415
advapi32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
user32.dll  C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll  6.3.9600.17415
gdi32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll   6.3.9600.17415
SHCore.dll  C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll  6.3.9600.17415
shlwapi.dll C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
shell32.dll C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll 6.3.9600.17415
uxtheme.dll C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll 6.3.9600.17415
dwmapi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll  6.3.9600.17415
twinapi.dll C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
d3d11.dll   C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll   6.3.9600.17415
dcomp.dll   C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll   6.3.9600.17415
sspicli.dll C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll 6.3.9600.17415
sechost.dll C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll 6.3.9600.17415
userenv.dll C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll 6.3.9600.17415
propsys.dll C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll 7.0.9600.17415
rpcrt4.dll  C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll  6.3.9600.17415
slc.dll C:\Windows\System32\slc.dll 6.3.9600.17031
profapi.dll C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
dxgi.dll    C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll    6.3.9600.17415
sppc.dll    C:\Windows\System32\sppc.dll    6.3.9600.17031
imm32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll   6.3.9600.17415
msctf.dll   C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll   6.3.9600.17415
kernel.appcore.dll  C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll  6.3.9600.17415
CRYPTBASE.dll   C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll   6.3.9600.17415
bcryptPrimitives.dll    C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll    6.3.9600.17415
ole32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll   6.3.9600.17415
clbcatq.dll C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll 2001.12.10530.17415
winsta.dll  C:\Windows\System32\winsta.dll  6.3.9600.17415
Bcp47Langs.dll  C:\Windows\System32\Bcp47Langs.dll  6.3.9600.17415
IDStore.dll C:\Windows\System32\IDStore.dll 6.3.9600.17415
samlib.dll  C:\Windows\System32\samlib.dll  6.3.9600.17415
SETTINGSYNCPOLICY.dll   C:\Windows\System32\SETTINGSYNCPOLICY.dll   6.3.9600.17415
dui70.dll   C:\Windows\System32\dui70.dll   6.3.9600.17415
comctl32.dll    C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17415_none_6240486fecbd8abb\comctl32.dll    6.10.9600.17415
duser.dll   C:\Windows\System32\duser.dll   6.3.9600.17415
SndVolSSO.DLL   C:\Windows\System32\SndVolSSO.DLL   6.3.9600.17415
hid.dll C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll 6.3.9600.17415
MMDevAPI.dll    C:\Windows\System32\MMDevAPI.dll    6.3.9600.17415
devobj.dll  C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll  6.3.9600.17415
cfgmgr32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
oleacc.dll  C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll  7.2.9600.17415
D3D10Warp.dll   C:\Windows\System32\D3D10Warp.dll   6.3.9600.17415
twinui.dll  C:\Windows\System32\twinui.dll  6.3.9600.17415
twinapi.appcore.dll C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll 6.3.9600.17415
xmllite.dll C:\Windows\System32\xmllite.dll 6.3.9600.17415
Windows.UI.Immersive.dll    C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll    6.3.9600.17415
ntmarta.dll C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll 6.3.9600.17415
cryptsp.dll C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll 6.3.9600.17415
rsaenh.dll  C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll  6.3.9600.17415
bcrypt.dll  C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll  6.3.9600.17415
actxprxy.dll    C:\Windows\System32\actxprxy.dll    6.3.9600.17416
windowscodecs.dll   C:\Windows\System32\windowscodecs.dll   6.3.9600.17415
explorerframe.dll   C:\Windows\System32\explorerframe.dll   6.3.9600.17415
windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovider.dll  C:\Windows\System32\windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovider.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wldp.dll    C:\Windows\System32\wldp.dll    6.3.9600.17415
wtsapi32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
PhotoMetadataHandler.dll    C:\Windows\System32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll    6.3.9600.17415
twinui.appcore.dll  C:\Windows\System32\twinui.appcore.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wpncore.dll C:\Windows\System32\wpncore.dll 6.3.9600.17415
DWrite.dll  C:\Windows\System32\DWrite.dll  6.3.9600.17415
UIAnimation.dll C:\Windows\System32\UIAnimation.dll 6.3.9600.17415
nvwgf2umx.dll   C:\Windows\System32\nvwgf2umx.dll   10.18.13.5330
version.dll C:\Windows\System32\version.dll 6.3.9600.17415
psapi.dll   C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll   6.3.9600.17415
wlidprov.dll    C:\Windows\System32\wlidprov.dll    6.3.9600.17415
samcli.dll  C:\Windows\System32\samcli.dll  6.3.9600.17415
netutils.dll    C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll    6.3.9600.17415
thumbcache.dll  C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll  6.3.9600.17415
linkinfo.dll    C:\Windows\System32\linkinfo.dll    6.3.9600.17415
urlmon.dll  C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll  11.0.9600.17416
iertutil.dll    C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll    11.0.9600.17416
wininet.dll C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll 11.0.9600.17416
secur32.dll C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll 6.3.9600.17415
InputSwitch.dll C:\Windows\System32\InputSwitch.dll 6.3.9600.17415
Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.dll 6.3.9600.17415
lockscreencn.dll    C:\Windows\System32\lockscreencn.dll    6.3.9600.17230
d2d1.dll    C:\Windows\System32\d2d1.dll    6.3.9600.17415
UIAutomationCore.DLL    C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.DLL    7.2.9600.17415
stobject.dll    C:\Windows\System32\stobject.dll    6.3.9600.17415
batmeter.dll    C:\Windows\System32\batmeter.dll    6.3.9600.17415
sxs.dll C:\Windows\System32\sxs.dll 6.3.9600.17415
es.dll  C:\Windows\System32\es.dll  2001.12.10530.17415
msftedit.dll    C:\Windows\System32\msftedit.dll    6.3.9600.17415
msimg32.dll C:\Windows\System32\msimg32.dll 6.3.9600.17415
Windows.Globalization.dll   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Globalization.dll   6.3.9600.17415
globinputhost.dll   C:\Windows\System32\globinputhost.dll   6.3.9600.17415
ninput.dll  C:\Windows\System32\ninput.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wevtapi.dll C:\Windows\System32\wevtapi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
tiptsf.dll  C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll   6.3.9600.17415
atlthunk.dll    C:\Windows\System32\atlthunk.dll    6.3.9600.17415
npmproxy.dll    C:\Windows\System32\npmproxy.dll    6.3.9600.17415
IPHLPAPI.DLL    C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL    6.3.9600.17415
nsi.dll C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
winnsi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wlanapi.dll C:\Windows\System32\wlanapi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
ntshrui.dll C:\Windows\System32\ntshrui.dll 6.3.9600.17415
prnfldr.dll C:\Windows\System32\prnfldr.dll 6.3.9600.17415
winspool.drv    C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv    6.3.9600.17415
DXP.dll C:\Windows\System32\DXP.dll 6.3.9600.17415
GdiPlus.dll C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17415_none_932b3b5547500489\GdiPlus.dll 6.3.9600.17415
setupapi.dll    C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll    6.3.9600.17415
shdocvw.dll C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll 6.3.9600.17415
WinTypes.dll    C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll    6.3.9600.17415
srvcli.dll  C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll  6.3.9600.17415
AudioSes.dll    C:\Windows\System32\AudioSes.dll    6.3.9600.17415
netprofm.dll    C:\Windows\System32\netprofm.dll    6.3.9600.17415
Actioncenter.dll    C:\Windows\System32\Actioncenter.dll    6.3.9600.17415
crypt32.dll C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll 6.3.9600.17415
msasn1.dll  C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll  6.3.9600.17415
cscapi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\cscapi.dll  6.3.9600.17415
Syncreg.dll C:\Windows\System32\Syncreg.dll 2007.94.9600.17415
wcmapi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\wcmapi.dll  6.3.9600.17415
msiltcfg.dll    C:\Windows\System32\msiltcfg.dll    5.0.9600.17415
msi.dll C:\Windows\System32\msi.dll 5.0.9600.17415
wpdshserviceobj.dll C:\Windows\System32\wpdshserviceobj.dll 6.3.9600.17415
PortableDeviceTypes.dll C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceTypes.dll 6.3.9600.17415
PortableDeviceApi.dll   C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceApi.dll   6.3.9600.17415
wintrust.dll    C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll    6.3.9600.17415
sqmapi.dll  C:\Program Files\Windows Portable Devices\sqmapi.dll    6.3.9600.17415
cscui.dll   C:\Windows\System32\cscui.dll   6.3.9600.17415
cscdll.dll  C:\Windows\System32\cscdll.dll  6.3.9600.17415
AltTab.dll  C:\Windows\System32\AltTab.dll  6.3.9600.17415
authui.dll  C:\Windows\System32\authui.dll  6.3.9600.17415
NetworkExplorer.dll C:\Windows\System32\NetworkExplorer.dll 6.3.9600.17415
cscobj.dll  C:\Windows\System32\cscobj.dll  6.3.9600.17415
DropboxExt64.26.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Dropbox\Client\DropboxExt64.26.dll   1.0.0.26
pnidui.dll  C:\Windows\System32\pnidui.dll  6.3.9600.17415
SettingMonitor.dll  C:\Windows\System32\SettingMonitor.dll  6.3.9600.17415
NetworkStatus.dll   C:\Windows\System32\NetworkStatus.dll   6.3.9600.17415
EhStorShell.dll C:\Windows\System32\EhStorShell.dll 6.3.9600.17415
wkscli.dll  C:\Windows\System32\wkscli.dll  6.3.9600.17415
bthprops.cpl    C:\Windows\System32\bthprops.cpl    6.3.9600.17415
BluetoothApis.dll   C:\Windows\System32\BluetoothApis.dll   6.3.9600.17415
srchadmin.dll   C:\Windows\System32\srchadmin.dll   7.0.9600.17415
provsvc.dll C:\Windows\System32\provsvc.dll 6.3.9600.17415
ws2_32.dll  C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll  6.3.9600.17415
MrmCoreR.dll    C:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll    6.3.9600.17416
dhcpcsvc6.DLL   C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL   6.3.9600.17415
dhcpcsvc.dll    C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll    6.3.9600.17415
mssprxy.dll C:\Windows\System32\mssprxy.dll 7.0.9600.17415
SyncCenter.dll  C:\Windows\System32\SyncCenter.dll  6.3.9600.17415
imapi2.dll  C:\Windows\System32\imapi2.dll  6.3.9600.17415
hgcpl.dll   C:\Windows\System32\hgcpl.dll   6.3.9600.17415
Windows.UI.Search.dll   C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Search.dll   6.3.9600.17415
wincorlib.DLL   C:\Windows\System32\wincorlib.DLL   6.3.9600.17415
WSClient.dll    C:\Windows\System32\WSClient.dll    6.3.9600.17415
WSShared.dll    C:\Windows\System32\WSShared.dll    6.3.9600.17415
WSSync.dll  C:\Windows\System32\WSSync.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wer.dll C:\Windows\System32\wer.dll 6.3.9600.17415
ELSCore.dll C:\Windows\System32\ELSCore.dll 6.3.9600.17415
Windows.UI.dll  C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll  6.3.9600.17415
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll 6.3.9600.17415
searchfolder.dll    C:\Windows\System32\searchfolder.dll    6.3.9600.17415
StructuredQuery.dll C:\Windows\System32\StructuredQuery.dll 7.0.9600.17415
msxml6.dll  C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll  6.30.9600.17415
ieframe.dll C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll 11.0.9600.17416
UIRibbonRes.dll C:\Windows\System32\UIRibbonRes.dll 6.3.9600.17415
mpr.dll C:\Windows\System32\mpr.dll 6.3.9600.17415
dlnashext.dll   C:\Windows\System32\dlnashext.dll   12.0.9600.17415
DevDispItemProvider.dll C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll 6.3.9600.17415
winmm.dll   C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll   6.3.9600.17415
WINMMBASE.dll   C:\Windows\System32\WINMMBASE.dll   6.3.9600.17415
virtdisk.dll    C:\Windows\System32\virtdisk.dll    6.3.9600.17415
fltLib.dll  C:\Windows\System32\fltLib.dll  6.3.9600.17415
MSWB7.dll   C:\Windows\System32\MSWB7.dll   6.3.9600.17415
WorkFoldersShell.dll    C:\Windows\System32\WorkFoldersShell.dll    6.3.9600.17415
SkydriveShell.dll   C:\Windows\System32\SkydriveShell.dll   6.3.9600.17416
chartv.dll  C:\Windows\System32\chartv.dll  6.3.9600.17415
fzshellext_64.dll   C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\fzshellext_64.dll 3.11.0.2
apprepapi.dll   C:\Windows\System32\apprepapi.dll   6.3.9600.17415
tbs.dll C:\Windows\System32\tbs.dll 6.3.9600.17415
pcacli.dll  C:\Windows\System32\pcacli.dll  6.3.9600.17415
sfc_os.dll  C:\Windows\System32\sfc_os.dll  6.3.9600.17415
IconCodecService.dll    C:\Windows\System32\IconCodecService.dll    6.3.9600.17415
RstrtMgr.dll    C:\Windows\System32\RstrtMgr.dll    6.3.9600.17415
ncrypt.dll  C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll  6.3.9600.17415
ntasn1.dll  C:\Windows\System32\ntasn1.dll  6.3.9600.17415
devrtl.dll  C:\Windows\System32\devrtl.dll  6.3.9600.17415
mlang.dll   C:\Windows\System32\mlang.dll   6.3.9600.17415
shellExt.dll    C:\Program Files\ESET\ESET NOD32 Antivirus\shellExt.dll 8.0.312.0
syncui.dll  C:\Windows\System32\syncui.dll  6.3.9600.17415
synceng.dll C:\Windows\System32\synceng.dll 6.3.9600.17415
ContextMenuShim64.dll   C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat Elements\ContextMenuShim64.dll    11.0.0.379
comdlg32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
7-zip.dll   C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7-zip.dll    9.35.0.0
wscinterop.dll  C:\Windows\System32\wscinterop.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wscapi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\wscapi.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wscui.cpl   C:\Windows\System32\wscui.cpl   6.3.9600.17415
dpapi.dll   C:\Windows\System32\dpapi.dll   6.3.9600.17415
werconcpl.dll   C:\Windows\System32\werconcpl.dll   6.3.9600.17415
framedynos.dll  C:\Windows\System32\framedynos.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wercplsupport.dll   C:\Windows\System32\wercplsupport.dll   6.3.9600.17415
hcproviders.dll C:\Windows\System32\hcproviders.dll 6.3.9600.17415
ieproxy.dll C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll  11.0.9600.17416
UIRibbon.dll    C:\Windows\System32\UIRibbon.dll    6.3.9600.17415
sfc.dll C:\Windows\System32\sfc.dll 6.3.9600.16384
PlayToDevice.dll    C:\Windows\System32\PlayToDevice.dll    12.0.9600.17415
wpdshext.dll    C:\Windows\System32\wpdshext.dll    6.3.9600.17415
EhStorAPI.dll   C:\Windows\System32\EhStorAPI.dll   6.3.9600.17415
```

**Update:** I've forget to mention; Sometimes computer freezes for 10-30 seconds during boot. And then it continues normally.

Comment: Was this the first power on after the spill?

Comment: No it worket fine for weeks. I'm now trying with Win 7 in case Win 8 installation was buggy.

Comment: create a crash dump and share it: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've updated my question wiht a link to dmp file. I've tried to analyse it using BlueScreenView but it showed nothing.

Comment: the crash happens at function "explorerframe!CAddressEditBox::s_ComboExSubclassWndProc/comctl32!Str_Set". I can't see any 3rd party tools. Do try/error approach by disabling 3rd party shell extensions until you find the one that causes it.

Comment: also try to delete all entries from Addressbar History: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-unwanted-items-from-addressbar-history-in-windows-explorer/

Comment: I don't store history of opened programs etc. Maybe dropbox causes this but I'm not very shure. http://superuser.com/questions/564975/how-do-i-prevent-windows-8-file-explorer-from-regularly-crashing-about-every-10

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've uninstalled dropbox and no crashes yet. I've contacted dropbox for the case. I guess there was an update lately for sync status icons of folders/files on Windows 8

Comment: ok, but you need  strong nerves, they fixed 1 issue that I had in the dropbox extension only after several months.

Comment: And Dropbox suppord replied that the problem is not related with dropbox and I should contact Microsoft. Actually explorer crashed again. Now I've closed Google Drive, which I've installed after Dropbox.

Comment: have you tried to delete all history items?

Comment: I just did it. I have noticed that crashes occur more often while working with programs that have couple text boxes in their GUI and especially when they make interaction with explorer. Like open file dialogs or selecting path.

Comment: try the old clean boot approach to disable all 3rd party tools until you find the tool that cause the issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135

Comment: I've asked my Microsoft contact and he said, that he sees other reports with the same crash signature. But there are not enough crashes that Microsoft analyzes the crash deeper.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you for your concern. I guess Visual Studio's Web Essentials plugin could cause such crashes. One of my websites was stored inside Dropbox. And other stransge thing is Dropbox status icons keep refreshing (for each file/folder even it is uploaded) at Explorer's navigation pane.

Comment: *try* and run in terminal: `sfc /scannow`

Comment: ok, remove it and look what happens.

Comment: @Yousef's Thank you, I already executed this command but it had no effect.

Comment: I've forget to mention; Sometimes computer freezes for 10-30 seconds during boot, right after windows logo shows. And then it continues normally. I gues it was waiting response from the external drives.

Comment: I think it was a windows or dropbox issue and I don't have the problem now.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft said, that they see other reports with the same crash signature in their telemetry data. But there are not enough crashes that Microsoft analyzes the crash deeper.

You have to try the old clean boot approach to disable all 3rd party tools until you find the tool that cause the issue:

**How to perform a clean boot in Windows** 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135

Answer (score -2):

From your exception error code `0xC0000005`there might be possible infection of files in your computer ,**try to Check your BCD and do the fix if necessary**

In Windows open **CMD as Administrator** and type `BCDEdit` and enter,  if your Windows Boot Loader Path is `xOsload.exe` then you need to **remove some files and repair your BCD**.

NOTE:  you will need to re-activate Windows afterwards, so make sure you have your Windows 8.1 key handy.

```
Boot to Windows Repair - Command
Del D:\Windows\System32\xOsload.exe
Del D:\Windows\System32\xNtKrnl.exe
Del D:\Windows\System32\Drivers\oem-drv64.sys
attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s
ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: I don't see any executables. My bootloader is EFI. BOOTMGFW.EFI & winload.efi

Comment: @magicandre1981 dear friend as per exception message and code i have delivered the solution,could u kindly clarify how it makes non-sense reply my dear friend :)

Comment: this is a nonsense answer because it has nothing to do with the question. He gets an user mode application crash. The issue is caused by an **STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION** error, which means wrong or corrupted error was used. This has **NOTHING** to do with Boot Configuration data (BCD).