# right click crashes explorer.exe on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, right-click

I'm having some troubles with Windows 10. Everytime I right click certain files, Explorer.exe restarts completely. I don't know why, but it is really annoying to use the computer like that. Before you ask, I haven't done anything to the registry, nor to the group permissions. I gave Users full access to the hard drive because I'm the only user.

I've discovered it crashes when I right click `.dll` and `.exe` files. I don't know if it crashes with other file extensions, I've only tried with those ones.

Comment: Try running `sfc /scannow` from command line run as Administrator.

Comment: Your english is great, but it seems this might be related to a corruption in your context menu - specifically for `.exe` and `.dll` files. Have you looked at what things are listed in your context menu? If not, try [CCleaner's contest menu tool](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) or [one of these](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors).

Comment: possible duplicate of [/271118/right-click-on-mouse-crashes-windows-explorer](http://superuser.com/questions/271118/right-click-on-mouse-crashes-windows-explorer).

Comment: capture a crash dump and share the compressed dump so that I can look at it with a debugger: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: well, so far i've only installed winrar, klite codec pack, chrome, imgburn, vlc and up to date windows updates, I haven´t installed any other programs or apps, @magicandre1981 could you explain how to capture a crash dump?

Comment: @ojs I already did that and it didn't show any problem

Comment: @Dooley_labs I´m gonna try with ccleaner

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UEr_daxQHucmNYMHJiM3RkLWM/view?usp=sharing here's the crash dump you told me to do, after I inserted the first registry entry, explorer.exe crashed even more frequently, so I had to start the computer on "safe mode" in order to retrieve the dump files

Comment: ok, I got the dumps and will post an answer now. Import the uninstall.reg to stop AppVerifier/dump creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is caused by an extremely old Realtek Audio driver from 2008, which tries to free memory which contains a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section), which is not allowed:

```
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_LOCKS_LOCK_IN_FREED_HEAP (202)
Freeing heap block containing an active critical section.
This stop is generated if a heap allocation contains a critical section,
the allocation is freed and the critical section has not been deleted.
To debug this stop use the following debugger commands:
$ !cs -s parameter1 - dump information about this critical section.
$ ln parameter1 - to show symbols near the address of the critical section.
This should help identify the leaked critical section.
$ dps parameter2 - to dump the stack trace for this critical section initialization.
$ parameter3 and parameter4 might help understand where this heap block was
allocated (the size of the allocation is probably significant). 
Arguments:
Arg1: 0f26059c, Critical section address. Run !cs -s <address> to get more information. 
Arg2: 04a2d40c, Critical section initialization stack trace. Run dps <address> to dump the stack trace. 
Arg3: 0f260230, Heap block address. 
Arg4: 000020f8, Heap block size. 

STACK_TEXT: 
00 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
01 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
02 ntdll!RtlReportExceptionEx
03 ntdll!RtlReportException
04 verifier!AVrfpVectoredExceptionHandler
05 ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers
06 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
07 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
08 verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx
09 verifier!AVrfpFreeMemLockChecks
0a verifier!AVrfpFreeMemNotify
0b verifier!AVrfpRtlFreeHeap
0c msvcrt!free
0d verifier!AVrfp_delete
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0e RtkAPO
0f RtkAPO
10 ALSNDMGR!CPlApplet
11 OneDriveSettingSyncProvider!CUserTileProvider::_ValidateStream


-----------------------------------------
Critical section   = 0x0f26059c (+0xF26059C)
DebugInfo          = 0x0eb35358
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x020007d0


Stack trace for DebugInfo = 0x0eb35358:

0x711d8b53: verifier!AVrfpInitializeCriticalSectionCommon+0xF4
0x711d8cc1: verifier!AVrfpRtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x11
0x65277b05: RtkAPO+0x87B05
0x65278255: RtkAPO+0x88255
0x6527b5d6: RtkAPO+0x8B5D6
0x652738a7: RtkAPO+0x838A7
0x75c2e8e0: combase!CServerContextActivator::CreateInstance+0x1A0
0x75bd8f1a: combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0xBA
0x75c2edc2: combase!CApartmentActivator::CreateInstance+0xA2
0x75c2f105: combase!CProcessActivator::CCICallback+0x65
0x75c2f080: combase!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation+0x40
0x75c2f37b: combase!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext+0xDB
0x75c2f1f7: combase!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance+0x67
0x75bd8efb: combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0x9B
0x75bd714d: combase!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance+0xFD
0x75bd8f02: combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0xA2
0x75c27240: combase!ICoCreateInstanceEx+0xBE0
0x75c26509: combase!CComActivator::DoCreateInstance+0x149
0x75c28332: combase!CoCreateInstance+0x132
0x100078da: ALSNDMGR!CPlApplet+0x32BA

    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\RtkAPO.dll
    Image name: RtkAPO.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Dec 22 08:50:19 2008 (494F46BB)
    CheckSum:         0026D77A
    ImageSize:        0026C000
    File version:     11.0.6000.85
    Product version:  11.0.6000.85
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
    ProductName:      Realtek(r) LFX/GFX DSP component
    InternalName:     RTKAPODll
    OriginalFilename: RTKAPO.Dll
    ProductVersion:   11, 0, 6000, 85
    FileVersion:      11, 0, 6000, 85
    FileDescription:  Realtek(r) LFX/GFX DSP component
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (c) Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 2008
```

So, install a newer realtek driver version to fix the issue.

Comment: all right, thanks a lot for your answer, as soon as I get home (I'm at work) I will try that and let you know if explorer.exe stops crashing

Comment: the manufacturer doesn't offer really up to date drivers, this is an old generic pc, the newest driver they offer for realtek AC'97 is one from 2009 made for Windows Vista and 7, I'm going to install it and let you know if that fixes the issue

Comment: does this driver fixes it? If not, buy a new sound card with a newer sound chip that gets updated drivers.

Comment: yup, thanks a lot, it fixed the issue, here, in Venezuela, is not that easy to buy pc parts, so you helped me save a lot of money