# Explorer crashes (and restarts) when right clicking explorer.exe or any links to it

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I noticed in my taskbar first that I could no longer open a new explorer window by clicking on the pinned folder (Left, middle and right-clicking all immediately cause explorer to hang and restart).

I am able to start a new explorer window by either Win+R and typing `explorer.exe` or by using the start menu "File Explorer" button that is baked into the start menu. When going to `C:\Windows` directly and attempting to right click on `explorer.exe`, explorer hangs and restarts. Left clicking on this file yields expected results.

The Product/File version of this file is 10.0.10586.0.

Comment: Sounds like you have a malfunctioning context menu entry.  Try the tool mentioned here and see if disabling 3rd party shell extensions helps: http://superuser.com/a/248638/23133

Comment: I'll try this, but right clicking in any other context (IE inside of an explorer window on any other file, or on the desktop) works fine.

Comment: captrue a crash dump (http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU), zip the dmp and share it. I'll look at the dmp with a debugger.

Comment: @magicandre1981 There is no localDump created from my actions. I am not 100% sure if my error is fully crashing explorer, but it appears similarly to what explorer does crash, only the explorer windows I had open already are still open afterward.

Comment: look in the eventlog if you see application crash events. Maybe the Explorer just hangs